# Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '£75.92'

Tags: php, mysql

Im new to this all and I keep getting this warning and can't seem to make it go away.
I am supposed to make it display surnmaes begining with certain letter which I can do but can't make it display payment under £80.
All the values:

```
INSERT INTO w1773764_OneOff_Payment (w1773764_PaymentRefNo, w1773764_PaymentDate, w1773764_PaymentAmount, w1773764_custNo, w1773764_custSurname)
VALUES
    (101, '2022-09-13', '£75.92', '1','PATTERSON'),
    (102, '2020-07-04', '£90.00', '2', 'PATIENZIE'),
    (103, '2017-12-15', '£50.22', '3','PATEL' ),
    (104, '2021-04-24', '£66.73', '4','PATRICK'),
    (105, '2021-10-17', '£100.23', '5', 'ONE'),
    (106, '2020-01-30', '£85.00', '6', 'THOMAS')
;
```

This is wht i was trying to use but kept getting a double value warning:

SELECT w1773764_PaymentAmount, w1773764_custSurname FROM w1773764_OneOff_Payment WHERE (w1773764_custSurname LIKE 'PAT%')AND w1773764_PaymentAmount<=80.00

Would really appricate if someobne can help me out here.

Comment: It sounds like `w1773764_PaymentAmount` is expecting a numeric value, not a string.  Is that the case in the table definition?  If so, you need to give it a numeric value, not a string.

Comment: what's the type of your w1773764_PaymentAmount ?

Comment: `£` should not be in a double column. Double columns are only for numbers, periods, and negative symbols.

Comment: Plus: currency should not be stored a floating point value to avoid rounding issues. Better use DECIMAL instead.

Comment: what do you mean by type? sorry if it sounds stupid, im still a student learning all this so its kinda tricky. @soma

Comment: Mysql is a database with strict data typing, not excel that has flexible data types and that can convert between various data types on the fly! `'£75.92'` is a string, not a numeric value because of the leading `£` sign. Apparently, your field expects a pure numeric value, so just remove `£` from your values. (And no need for the single quotes around the numbers either)

Comment: Thank you for everyone who commented and helped. All I had to do was take out the £. :)

Comment: @Shadow thank you, explained it well man

Comment: @jaskaran trye this : SELECT w1773764_PaymentAmount, w1773764_custSurname FROM w1773764_OneOff_Payment WHERE (w1773764_custSurname LIKE 'PAT%')AND CAST(SUBSTR(w1773764_PaymentAmount,2) as FLOAT)
<=80.00